# Split a single list to 'x' numbers of lists during runtime?

Tags: c#, list, linq, sorting

I have a list which I want split up into x numbers of lists during runtime. Imagine a list "original" as such: (note that I do not know the number of values inside the list or what the values are before runtime)

```
1199.17
1199.17
1161.67
1161.67
1161.67
1161.67
1161.67
1199.17
1349.17
1349.17
1349.17
1311.67
1311.67
1311.67
```

I want to split this list into different list of the same numbers
So list1 would be:

```
1199.17
1199.17
```

list2:

```
1161.67
1161.67
1161.67
1161.67
1161.67
```

etc.....

As you can imagine, because I do not know what the size or values inside "original" list is I do not know how many lists need to be created during runtime. How do I go about doing this in C#?

Comment: Try the linq groupby function: https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/linq/grouping-data-the-groupby-method/

Comment: As stated above, use `GroupBy()`, but to be clear you'll need to convert groups to lists: `var lists = numbers.GroupBy(x => x).Select(group => group.ToList()).ToList();` This will give you a list of lists of double (for your case).